# Updating a post without escaping ampersands?

Tags: posts, wp-update-post, escaping

I've found that `wp_update_post()` escapes all ampersands provided in the post's `post_content`.  I'm trying to update a post without converting ampersands to `&amp;`.  (I need to add plaintext URLs (*not* links) to the `post_content` field of posts).  So, I'm trying to find a way to use `wp_update_post()` with escaping disabled, or perhaps another function in its place.

One approach would be to exercise `$wpdb` directly, but I'd rather not as that seems like a last resort to me.

One observation I've made is that if you use the "Text" view to edit a post via the admin interface, you can successfully add ampersands to the post_content without them being converted to `&amp;`.  However, it's taking me some time to trace through the code to find out how Wordpress accomplishes this.  Does anyone know how WP accomplishes this?

Ultimately, my question is, **what's the best way to update a post with ampersand escaping "disabled"?**

Answer (score 4):

That is correct, the updating in the Admin section does not change the `&` to `&amp;` while the wp_update_post() function (which can be found under [/wp-includes/post.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/post.php) on line 3772) does but only when the user does not have the capability **unfiltered_html**, let me explain how I found this out, and what I recommend.

I did some tracing into this and found out that wp_update_post() calls wp_insert_post() internally as shown on line 3820

```
return wp_insert_post( $postarr, $wp_error );
```

wp_insert_post() calls sanitize_post() on line 3227

```
$postarr = sanitize_post( $postarr, 'db' );
```

Then on line 2176, this filter changes the `&` to `&amp;`

```
$value = apply_filters( "{$field_no_prefix}_save_pre", $value );
```

In particular there is a filter called `content_save_pre` or in my case `title_save_pre` since I am facing the same issue with the title.

Now, onto the Admin page which uses [/wp-admin/post.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/post.php)

You can see the actual save is on line 205

```
$post_id = edit_post();
```

And `edit_post()` function can be found under [/wp-admin/includes/post.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/post.php) on line 208

```
function edit_post( $post_data = null ) {
```

The actual update is being done on line 382

```
$success = wp_update_post( $post_data );
```

Which shows that Wordpress uses the same wp_update_post() function internally.

Turns out that there is a filter named 'wp_filter_kses' which is not being used by Wordpress Admin that is making all the difference. Although you can remove it by using:

```
remove_filter('content_save_pre', 'wp_filter_kses');
```

or in my case

```
remove_filter('title_save_pre', 'wp_filter_kses');
```

Or as @rinogo mentioned, you can use kses_remove_filters() to remove all kses filters.

However, these filters are set by [/wp-includes/kses.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/kses.php) on line 1934 after it checks if the user has the capability of "unfiltered_html"

```
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'unfiltered_html' ) ) {
    kses_init_filters();
    }
```

If `kses_init_filters()` gets called, then the user who is trying to update the post is not trusted enough and does not have the proper capability.

I would recommend that authentication gets handled properly rather than removing the filters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how WP's admin interface handles this (e.g. the scenario I referenced in the question), but I found a way to accomplish this:

```
//Disable KSES
kses_remove_filters();          

$update_rval = wp_update_post($updates);

//Reenable KSES
kses_init_filters();
```

Note that "kses" functions are part of Wordpress' defense against evil code.  So, use this approach at your own risk.  KSES does a *lot* more than just escape ampersands.  If `$updates` contains trusted data (as in my case), you're probably safe using this approach.

---

Update: I ran into another scenario in which Wordpress was happily running my JS but STILL escaping ampersands... I managed to get around this issue by substituting `String.fromCharCode(38)` in for every `&` character I needed in the URL.

Comment: Fun trivia: KSES is a recursive acronym meaning, "KSES Stops Evil Scripts"

Comment: Also, researching this a bit more, it looks like someone has blogged about this.  And, as it turns out, that person was me.  Facepalm? :) http://endorkins.com/2013/08/27/disable-wordpress-kses-to-prevent-html-filtering/

Comment: Here I am... Again.  Discovering my own question on wordpress.SE. :)

Comment: ...and again 

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Basil,
Your answer helped me, but instead of altering filters all I needed to do was add the capability "unfiltered_html" to the User Roles that were having this issue.

Comment: Try adding a comment on his answer instead of adding an answer

Comment: thanks @rinogo, but I feel my answer is different enough then Basil's and is the preferred answer I was looking for.

Comment: That works, too, but you should at least add code/info so that your answer stands on its own.